# Blocking ads with hosts file doesn't always work in Firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, dns, internet, hosts

I'm running Firefox on Linux and doing adblocking at the system-level using `/etc/hosts` from [StevenBlack Hosts](https://github.com/stevenblack/hosts) on GitHub, but some websites, such as regional [news](https://n-tv.de) and [magazine](https://golem.de) sites, still show some ads.

How do I completely prevent this?

Comment: I think you'll have to resort to an extension like uBlock Origin (my favorite, but there are others) to completely remove ads, because most of them are displayed thanks to redirections from the page you visit to advertisement platforms such as Taboola and the like, so that certain frames in the page don't belong to the domain you visit, but to the advertiser's. Adblockers can prevent that, hosts can't, because it only works on the basis of URL, domains or IP addresses you feed it for first connection. What happens once you're on the webpage you wish to visit is out of hosts hands.

Comment: Simple answer: the advert sites hosting the adverts aren't on the block list.  That repo includes MVPS hosts, which is the most extensive list of adblocking I know of, so the easiest way to resolve this would be to trace what hostnames those adverts are resolving from, then add those hosts to the `hosts` file

Answer (score 1):

Ad blockiing is reactive, not proactive.  Blocking ads via the hosts file simply blocks *known* domain names that serve ads.  New domains and IP addresses are always being created to serve ads.

Additionally, there are many methods of serving ads, with new methods being come up with.

Simply put, ad blockers are very good, but will never be perfect.